# Export an MVVM View using MEF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mef, markup-extensions

The application that I'm building has several (10+) `[Module]` executables.

I would like to specify something like this in `[Module]View.xaml` file.

```
<Window ... 
    mef:ExportView ExpectingViewModel={x:Type [Module]ViewModel}
>
</Window>
```

where `mef:ExportView` is a [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx) which prepares the parts for the MEF composer.

Currently,...

- In `[Module]View.xaml.cs` file I mark my View with an `ExportView(typeof([Module]ViewModel))` attribute inside the .  (The typeof param specifies the expected ViewModel.)
- I also mark my ViewModel with an `[ExportViewModel]` attribute.
- (Both attributes derive from ExportAttribute.)
- Each executable's Application class also inherits from an `ApplicationBase` class which does the MEF composition and marries/links the View/ViewModel.

Now, I would like to be able to remove all code-behind from the `[Module]View.xaml.cs` to prevent myself and my co-workers from forgetting to markup the code-behind file.

I'm thinking this would require a custom MarkupExtension.  I'm familiar with the basics of MEF, as well as creating custom export attributes with metadata.  However, I think this solution would require deriving from some of the [MEF primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd454610.aspx).

Comment: I don't need an exact solution; just "Derive ExportDefinition and do bli. Derive ComposablePart and do bla.  When you compose, do ji."

Comment: Interesting question. I personally think It's not that much of overhead, but maybe using T4 template you would be able to solve this? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7078546/724944

Comment: @surfen: That question is an interesting read. I think that OP's goal is to generate huge amounts of code (similar to LightSwitch, as accepted answer point #5 mentions).  I thought about doing `InheritedExport`, but this would NOT allow me to get the ViewModel type metadata that I'm looking for.  I also know that I could do the `InheritedExport`, instanciate all Views and scan the `ExportViewExtension`, but I'd rather use `Lazy<T, TMetadata>`.  (The last option may be my only one.)